# How to determine elements position relative to (grand^N)parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have elements A and B. B can be either a direct child to A or there can be 0 to N elements between them.

I need to know how B is positioned relative to A, or more specifically: how far top-left corner of B is from each of A:s bounds.

Note that A can have some parent and may have overflow:auto set.

If there are no better ways, each parent in between B and A can be accessed.

I can also iterate A:s parents right to <body>.

EDIT: example:

```
<div class="a">
    <div>
      foobar
      <div class="b">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

var a = $(".a");
var b = $(".b");

var bTopLeftDistanceToATopBound = ?;
var bTopLeftDistanceToABottomBound = ?;
var bTopLeftDistanceToARightBound = ?;
var bTopLeftDistanceToALeftBound = ?;
```

Comment: You question is not clear would you like to elaborate little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
return {
    top: b.offset().top-a.offset().top,
    bottom: a.height()-
        (b.offset().top-a.offset().top),
    left: b.offset().left-a.offset().left,
    right: a.width()-
        (b.offset().left-a.offset().left)
}
```